# Xamarin Google Play Services component shows "incomplete"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have installed the Google Play Services Xamarin component, but it shows "incomplete".

[image]

Looking at the documentation it says it requires API Level 16.

[image]

And my project is targeting 19 as a minimum.

[image]

Why does this say "incomplete"?

Comment: Hey John, I highly recommend using the NuGet packages for Google Play Services. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location/
Secondly, the newer packages require `Android 7.0+` to install. Thus ensure your `Compile Version` in the `Application` tab is at least Android 7.0 or above.

Comment: I took a look at the component page and this getting started article has not been updated for a long time. Secondly components should have some logs in your output window or if you right click on the "Incomplete" reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bypassed the Component store and used NuGet.  Everything works fine.